# Haskell - Apply list of functions to a variable

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have been trying to implement a function that applies a list of functions given as a parameter to a given variable. I have been running into various type errors with infinite types and type mismatches. Below is draft using recursion I believe is close to working, but keep running in to type mismatches. I am hard stuck in this swamp of issues and have no clue how to progress.

```
applyList :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
applyList [] variable = variable
applyList (f:fs) variable = applyList fs $(\f variable -> f variable)
```

Here is my another draft solution using foldl, no success there either.

```
applyList :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
applyList fs variable = foldl (\variable f -> f variable) variable fs
```

Example usage:

```
   applyList [] "foo" ==> "foo"
   applyList [] 1     ==> 1
   applyList [(++"bar")] "foo" ==> "foobar"
   applyList [reverse, tail, (++"bar")] "foo" ==> "raboo"
   applyList [(3*), (2^), (+1)] 0 ==> 6
   applyList [(+1), (2^), (3*)] 0 ==> 2
```

Comment: If you want the output of one function to be the input of the next, with an indeterminate length list of functions, then the function list must be of type `[(a -> a)]`, no?

Comment: `\f x -> f x` is just `($)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the first element of the list should be the outermost function, which means you don't need to do anything backwards or use `foldl`. Written explicitly, it'd be like this:

```
applyList [] variable = variable
applyList (f:fs) variable = f (applyList fs variable)
```

And with `foldr`:

```
applyList = foldr (.) id
```

Or even better:

```
applyList fs variable = foldr ($) variable fs
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're trying to write two different functions. Let's take a look at them separately. If you want this signature,

```
applyList :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
```

then you want to apply each function to the input and get a list of resutls. You don't need a lambda. You can simply apply `f` to the variable at each step of the recursion.

```
applyList :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
applyList [] _ = []
applyList (f:fs) variable = f variable : applyList fs variable
```

Now, Haskell provides a lot of higher-level operators for working with lists and data structures, so this sort of explicit recursion is not necessary as often as you might think. In particular, your `applyList` is really just the [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) function.

```
applyList :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
applyList fs a = map (\f -> f a) fs
```

And `\f -> f a` can be shorted to an [operator section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator)

```
applyList :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
applyList fs a = map ($ a) fs
```

Now the second one. If this is your goal

```
applyList :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
```

then you're right to want a fold. Based on your sample inputs and outputs, it looks like you want the rightmost function to apply first, so we can implement it with [`foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr)

```
applyList :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
applyList fs a = foldr (\f a -> f a) a fs
```

Again, `\f a -> f a` is just a cute way of writing `($)`

```
applyList :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
applyList fs a = foldr ($) a fs
```

If that doesn't look clear to you right now, don't fret. Stick with your recursive definition if you're more comfortable with that. This sort of higher-level thinking comes with time and experience in Haskell, and if you keep doing what you're doing, I promise you'll get there.

Comment: The first function has a lens operator [`(??) :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-63--63-)